# How to force a full recompilation of all files for every make?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm hoping to create a basic makefile template for small-scale C apps.  In this scenario, I'm less concerned with performance than clarity and want to recompile everything - All .h and .c files, and third-party .so files.

```
# Constants
#===============================================================================

# Specify the C complier
CC = gcc

# List the flags to pass to the compiler
#  -ggdb       Compile with debug information for gdb
#  -Wall       Give all diagnostic warnings
#  -O0         Do NOT optimize generated code
#  -m64        Generate code for a 64-bit environment
CFLAGS = -ggdb -Wall -O0 -m64

# Change the list of c source files into a list of object files by replacing
# the .c suffix with .o
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))

# List libraries
# m    Math library
LIBRARIES = -lm

# Specify the build target
TARGET = heyyou

# Rules
#===============================================================================
# $@ = left side of the colon, the target
$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Compiling $@..."
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES)
```

Comment: It's common to have a `clean` target that removes all generated files, including the executable and all object files. Then you can just run `make clean` to make sure all files will be rebuilt. But *don't* force full rebuild all the time, even if you just have a few files, if you build ten, twenty of more times a day that extra time accumulates. Let `make` handle the dependencies properly for you instead.

Comment: Or you can use version control, add all source files to it and then it keeps track of which files are generated. With *git* it's as simple as running `git clean -dfx` to kill all untracked files. Or it's common to configure known untracked files in `.gitignore` and use `git clean -dfX`.

Comment: the posted makefile fails to handle dependencies correctly, this is especially true of header files that are #include'd in the source files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have made Makefile properly considering all the decencies, simply use

```
make clean
```

If you have made a proper Makefile, all dependencies will be handled automatically and for every change you make in your file system, you don't have to do "make clean" every time. A simple "make" would be enough.
If you have not handled all the dependencies in make, then you will notice that changes that make in your source code won't reflect in binaries. 
So a simple work around this would be to add these lines in you Makefile

```
clean:
    rm *.so
    rm *.o
```

Now, for every compilation, do something like

```
make clean 
make
```

Its not a proper way to handle Makefile but its a saviour in some frustrating situation.

Comment: `clean` is not a magical target that make handles for you. You need to write it yourself and you need to account for having it clean all the things you expect it to clean if you want it to do that for you. The autotools automatically generate various clean targets for you, however.

Comment: I worked with kernel module compilation. What I meant by proper makefile is something like http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html. Here "make clean" takes care of everything. It removes all object and binary files.

Comment: So you mean "if you use a framework that has handled all the hard things for you" then? That's roughly the same as my autotools comment. And isn't at all helpful, on its own, with a hand-written makefile. (And that still has nothing to do with dependencies as-such.)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a clean function in your makefile,eg:

```
clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(PRG).elf *.eps *.png *.pdf *.bak
    rm -rf *.lst *.map
```

In your case you can add  also:

```
rm -rf $(OBJECTS)
```

Then you simply call `make clean` before call `make`

Answer (score 1):

you can indicate -B option in your make command line.

```
make -B
```

Comment: this answer can be improved with mentioning what the `-B` command actually does. I suggest a quote from a documentation.